# Magento URL translation for CMS pages names

Tags: php, magento, language-translation

I build the store with 2 views for two languages French and English and I have many CMS pages, like "about us" in English and the same page in French - "a propos".

In administration side the option "Add Store Code to Urls" is ON.

I have created 2 CMS pages "about-us" linked to English store view and another one "a-propos" linked to French store view.

When I’m in English store on "About us" page the URL is www.myurl.com/**en**/**about-us**/ but if I switch the language to French the language switcher brings me to www.myurl.com/**fr**/**about-us**/ instead of www.myurl.com/**fr**/**a-propos**/

So, the language switcher changes only the store code but not the page name.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is how magento works. If you want to change to another static block on your about page in some language you have to change the reference to the block id "about-us" to "a-propos" on the french site.

This page explains this quite good I think.
http://anothermarketer.com/how-to-translate-a-magento-theme/

Just add a comment to my answer if you need more help.